# How to save a default layout with 2 panels in MS Project?

Tags: microsoft-project

Honestly, I want to set a default layout when opening ms project. I can save a simple layout in 1 panel, but it didn't work when using 2 panels (tick option "Details" in tab "View").
Can any give suggestions to deal with this problem? I would really appreciate you guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the view tab create a new view and pick “combination” instead of single. This will let you pick the top pane and bottom pane views. Save it snd then in File | Options set it as your default view.

Comment: Thanks God, you're such a nice guy. Now I know one more feature in ms project because of you.